# SP2013: /_layouts/15/Usage.aspx report shows Blank (not zero) result

Tags: site-usage, space-usage

We are using SharePoint 2013 enterprise on-premise. By unknown reason, all site collection's `_layouts/15/Usage.aspx` report shows blank result. I understood it is an old SP2010 report. It is not even show up the link in Site Settings. However if site collection reach quota, an email will be sent to site collection admin with the hyperlink towards `_layouts/15/Usage.aspx`.

Our company have another SP2013 farm (standard) and its `_layouts/15/Usage.aspx` is working properly.

If the report load normal it should show something like:

> Current storage used:
>
> 3 MB
>
> Number of users:
>
> 8 users

However, on all our site collections it shows:

> Current storage used:
>
> Number of users:   users

Why? I check all site collection's popularity trend reports are correctly calculated. Checking the storage used in CA is working, too.

Answer (score 0):

The timer job **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing** was disabled (I believe it is disabled by default). After I enable and run it, the Usage.aspx report is working.